# Create hachures from DEM in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, dem, spatial-analyst

I have created contour lines from DEM and now I need to create hachures/bergstrich for them. I believe that spatial analyst should solve this, but I'm not used to it and I didn't found any similar tutorials.

Any solutions will help.

Comment: interesting question... i searched the web for it, but other than some experimental stuff in Visual Nature Studio and some papers, nothing came up.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/can-i-reproduce-this-classic-cartographic-hillshade-relief-effect-electronically

Answer (score 1):

[This question from July 2012](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/can-i-reproduce-this-classic-cartographic-hillshade-relief-effect-electronically/29596#29596) discussed creation of hachures in GIS. Here were the most useful answers:

> A quick Google search for "digital hachure map" found an article
>   written for *Cartographic Perspectives* in 2000 by Patrick Kennelly
>   called ["Desktop Hachure Maps from Digital Elevation
>   Models."](http://www.mbmg.mtech.edu/pdf/gis_hachure.pdf) While this
>   technique yielded something vaguely similar, it used more of a
>   pointilist technique rather than lines:
>
> [image: Digital hachure map, from Kennelly (2000)]
>
> Granted this article is more than 10 years old, so I bet with
>   improvements in computers and DEM resolution since then, creating a
>   better imitation of old-style Hachure maps would be possible based on
>   the slope and angle of elevation features.

And:

> This doesn't help with your goal unless you're willing to do some
>   coding, but Michal Migurski recently [did some
>   experiments](http://mike.teczno.com/notes/hachures.html) in automating
>   hachures, which [were built
>   on](http://www.flickr.com/photos/walkingsf/6951578888/) by Eric
>   Fischer.

Answer (score 0):

I have never generated hachures with ArcGIS and I've never heard of a ArcGIS tool that will create hachures.

You can try to use a line symbol to create simple hachures: Take the contour lines and use a Hash Line Symbol (in the Symbol Property Editor dialog box).

(A hillshade or a slope surface created with Spatial Anlalyst could be an alternative to hachures.)

Answer (score 0):

There's this but it's stylx so seems to be for ArcGIS Pro only, not ArcMap Desktop: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=87abe491604e45629e562903450947b7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).