# QGIS Raster Hillshade Classic Drawing Texture

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, dem, slope, hillshade

I found this drawing of a valley and really like the texture of it. I suppose this is a sort of hachure map drawn with dots. I was wondering if it was possible to recreate something similiar in QGIS (not ESRI) with a Lidar GeoTiff and Raster Analysis of Hillshade and Slope

[image]

This is what I would like to turn into the above.

[image]

Comment: These are called ["Hachure maps"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hachure_map). There was a similar question a while ago: [Can I reproduce this classic cartographic hillshade relief effect (hachures) electronically using modern DEM data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/can-i-reproduce-this-classic-cartographic-hillshade-relief-effect-hachures-ele)

Comment: I have obtained something similar playing with the symbology of a slope raster. Monogray, lower the minimum (I changed 0 to 69 for -10 to 69), increase brightness and contrast and add color (dark brown). Try to find the combination that works for you.
I have images, but I found the topic closed.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gv1kNKEGSEej7B6qgpPGUs1Z-NRUMsLksrCfpt2A1tE/edit